# How to obtain the token from the current user with jwt/express/node

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, token

I have a controller that receives an user that is trying to login via form. When all validations are checked, the user will be logged in and a token will be created in the following way:

```
const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id}, config.secret  ,{expiresIn: '24h'})
res.json({success: true, message: 'Sesión iniciada', token: token, user: {email: user.email}})
```

However, how do I access this token from another controller? I've seen that a good approach would be to create a middleware that intercepts such token, but I don't really know how to accomplish this.

I'd be happy only knowing how to get the token tho. I'm kinda new and I'm taking very small steps.

Comment: how are you making the requests from your front end?

Comment: With the localStorage.setItem(). I store the token and the user. I managed to login, but I have no idea how to get the data from the current user in the backend.

Comment: You need to return the token back to your client. Then the client, in future requests need to send this typically in the Authorization header to say I'm a valid user. On your server you can use [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt). This will make the decoded token available in the request object and you can get it in another controller

Comment: I'd suggest first to read more about [jwt](https://jwt.io/introduction). Then learn the whole idea of middleware. How to use [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, I need to learn more about this because, not only to jwt, I'm fairly new to js

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your client requests to send such token as @Vahid said.

Here's an example with [axios](https://axios-http.com/)

```js
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api',
  // From the docs:
  // `transformRequest` allows changes to the request data before it is sent to the server
  // This is only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH' and 'DELETE'
  // The last function in the array must return a string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
  // FormData or Stream
  // You may modify the headers object.
  transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
    headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('jwt')
    return data;
  }],
})

export default instance
```

In case you also need `GET` request you can add:

```js
export setAuthToken = (token) => {
  instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
}
```

Although you'll need to call it every time your JWT is renewed.

After that, you could catch it using the Middlewares to decode the token from the headers

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const authToken = req.headers['Authorization']
  if(authToken) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(authToken, config.secret)
      req.user = decoded.userId
      // Hopefully
      // req.user = getUserById(decoded.userId)
      next()
    } catch(e) {
      // Handle Errors or renewals
      req.user = null
      // You could either next() to continue or use 'res' to respond something
    }
    
  } else {
    // Throw 403 if should be authorized
    res.sendStatus(403)
  }
})
```

This way you should be able to access `req.user` on any route defined after your middleware.
Eg:

```js
app.post('/me', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})
```

Note that this is just one example of a global middleware. In other cases, you should be able to create custom middlewares based on which routes you want to protect or with which amount of permissions.

Comment: The jwt.verify did the trick! However, I'm experiencing some problems with the movement of the modules/data. It works just fine if I get everything into one file,but I'd like to split it up as I have many modules.
I've just posted another question about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69628913/request-returns-404-when-verifying-the-token-with-jwt-node-express
I'm sure I'm not moving the data right, but I don't know where the issue is tho